# Users management with Play! Framework 2.0.3

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm a complete newbie with Play! I'm a Django developer and I started using Play! a few days ago. 
I can't find information on how to register new users to my application. I don't want to use OAuth, I just want to manage users in my own database with passwords encryption. By the way, I'm using Java version.

Comment: It sounds like you're assuming that Play provides some sort of non-OAuth user management scheme for you. I don't know that's a valid assumption.

Comment: So I have to write the code for this task or find a third-party module? Do have any tutorials for this task?

Comment: Take a look at the samples, especially to this one which provides an exmple for authentication: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/zentasks

Comment: That example does not show how to create users, roles and that. It's not a good example.

Comment: There's also SecureSocial to provide authentication Play apps. Check the latest version here: http://www.securesocial.ws.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing ready yet, however I'd suggest you to use [play-authenticate](http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/) ([live demo](https://play-authenticate.herokuapp.com/)) as a base.

That's currently the most advanced solution for Play 2 for authentication and authorization. It combines deadbolt-2 for authorization (roles and permissions) + own authentication which makes it very comfortable stack to start with.

Although its base idea is deliver a way for authenticating users with OAuth - the `providers` are a configurable options, so you can disable it and base on e-mail provider only.

Note important for you it... **hasn't** build-in user management, however I can ensure you that in current state it requires adding just several actions to create what you need. I'm doing it in few of my projects and soon will send a pull request with that changes.

Edit: By default all providers are enabled with dummy credentials, of course it will fail to run. You need to disable them in `conf/play.plugins` (by just removing unwanted lines) most probably you have to **keep** only these lines to keep deadbolt + PA with mailer:

```
1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
10000:be.objectify.deadbolt.DeadboltPlugin
10005:service.PaUserServicePlugin
10040:providers.PaUsernamePasswordAuthProvider
```

Also don't forget to set proper SMTP credentials in `conf/play-authenticate/smtp.conf` to make sure that password recovering will work.

Comment: Ok great, I'll give it a try. It seems that the site has no documentation but I hope I'll find something on the web.

Comment: I downloaded from github but when I try to run the example of the samples folder I get this error "RuntimeException: Provider 'google' missing needed setting 'clientId'"

Comment: Its a bit unorganised, but here I found a documentation on getting started: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/Getting%20Started.md

Comment: I wonder if this is still the best option. Play-authenticate is not maintained anymore.